# Redirect to index page after logging in

Tags: javascript, php

Currently, I am developing a website with php in server side and javascript in client side.. Now, I am on the functionality of logging in where it cannot redirect to index.html even there is a data in database equally on the credentials input by the user.

I tried to create an alert if there is a response of the server side, and it was successful.

I want to know how to redirect the page if the user credentials has in the database.

This is the code:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnLogin').click(function(){
var username = $('#txtEmail').val();
var password = $('#txtpassword').val();
 var access = $('#slAccess').val();
        if(username==""){
            alert('please Enter username');
        }
 else if(password==""){
            alert('please Enter password');
        }
else{
$('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<span>Please Wait, User is being logged</span>');
var datasend = "username="+ username + "&password=" + password + "&access=" + password;
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'../examples/php/pLogin.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg){
                window.location.href = "index.html";

            }, error: function(e)
            {
                console.log(e)
            }

        });

        }

    })

});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    include("php_functions/config.php");
    session_start();
if($_POST['username'] != '' && $_POST['password'] !='') {
        // username and password sent from form 
        echo $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
        echo $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
        echo $myaccess = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['access']); 



        //$sql = "SELECT user_id  FROM user WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE Email = '$myusername' and Password = '$mypassword' and UserAccessID = '$myaccess'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count == 1) {
            //prevent session fixation attack
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername; 
            header("location: index.html");
        }
        }

?>
```

Also, the location of the index.html is `C:wamp\benchmark`

and the js and php also the html of login is in `C:wamp\benchmark\pages\examples`

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: Well in the Php file, you have added the line `header("location: index.html");`. This causes http header to be sent in response to the AJAX call. It is not needed because you are redirecting the user on client side using JavaScript. Try to remove this line from Php file

Comment: @NadirLatif Sir?? I want to redirect my page on the server side. how to do that?

Comment: Well if you want to redirect on server side, then you need to submit the form and not use Ajax. Once the form is submitted, the user can be redirected using Php header function

Answer (score 0):

You could send an error when the login fails, and the redirect URL when it passes. 
For example in your PHP:

```php
if ($count == 1) {
    //prevent session fixation attack
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
    die('Logged in');
} else {
    http_response_code(403);
    die();
}
```

And then in your JS:

```
success: function(msg){
    window.location.href = "index.html";
}, error: function(e) {
    alert('Login Failed')
}
```

Comment: is it on the client side sir to redirect the page after logging in?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean all redirection needs to be on the server side, right? Also, there is a tool that can deactivate a javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

With time to redirect ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";
    }, 5000);
});
```

Without time to redirect

```
window.location = "https://www.google.co.in";
```

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:

```
window.location.replace('https://www.google.co.in');
```

// Simulate a mouse click:

```
window.location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";
```

Comment: Is there a way sir to redirect the login.html page in index.html page in server side?? using the javascript?

Comment: try this example